# How to generate a local user profile for a new user account in Windows?

Tags: windows, user-profile

I have created a new local Windows account and want to modify some of the personal data for this new created profile. But if this account was never logged in, the profile data is not generated and so I cannot modify it. I want to modify things like the NTUSER.dat to customize the Current User Registry and prepare things in the user’s personal folder.
I cannot use the default profile, because in my application it should be possible to create more than one local user account with different settings. And these Settings should not be used for the next new created user account.

Is there a way to initiate this generation process for the user profile folder?

If not, is there a good way to automatically logon this new created user, wait until the profile has been generated and then logoff?

The solution should be able to work under Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

(I am using .NET 3.5 / C#, but I am open to all kind of answers as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend could help me and found the answer. This doesn't work under Windows 2000, but it works fine for Windows XP and Windows Vista, I will test Windows 7 later, but I guess it should work.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196070/en-us